# is_user_logged_in() throwing undefined function error

Tags: users, wp-user-query

I am running this simple conditional statement on my plugin page:

```
if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 's8w_ajax_login_init');
}
```

It is throwing a fatal undefined function error for `is_user_logged_in`. Am I missing something? I have several wp globals on the same page. Do I have to call something else for this to work?

Comment: Are you making a browser/form/ajax request directly to a PHP file in your plugin?

Comment: I think I might be... should the ajax function be on the theme function file? Not quite understanding the question.

Comment: No it shouldn't, you can't make requests directly to PHP files in themes and plugins, be that via AJAX or another way. It won't work as WP won't be loaded. For AJAX use the REST API to register an endpoint so you have a URL to make requests to, look up `register_rest_route`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because WordPress isn't loaded. Instead of making AJAX requests directly to PHP files in your theme, make them to a REST API endpoint.

For example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'petebolduc/v1', '/test/', array(
                'callback' => 'petebolduc_ajax'
        ) );
} );
function petebolduc( $parameters ) {
    $foo = $parameters['foo'];
    return "foo is " . $foo;
}
```

With that code, visiting: `example.com/wp-json/petebolduc/v1/test?foo=bar`

gives:

```php
"foo is bar"
```

Comment: Tom, I appreciate your help. If I'm understanding this: petebolduc would be my main plugin file... v1 would be some folder... and test would be the file where the ajax function resides or is it just a just a ghost url?

Comment: What I am attempting to do is follow this article to set up an ajax login form: http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/#comment-4400 In he says the functions should be placed on the functions file in the theme, but in my wp ignorance I figured I could just put them on the plugin file as it loads as well.

Comment: You can put them in a plugin too, WP sees no difference between a hook in a themes `functions.php` and a plugin, but the browser shouldn't make direct requests to either. The old way was to make requests to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` but the new way will handle a lot of things for you and give human readable error messages. Look up the other options for `register_rest_route` and it'll show you how to tell it what parameters you're giving it, and let you validate automatically, as well as control who's allowed to use it

Comment: Thanks Tom... I was unaware of the Rest Api... Since your feedback last night I have been studying it intently as I now see it potential. As I thought about WP not seeing a difference between a hook in the function.php and a plugin. Thanks for clarifying.